# ARM Template failure via Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

We are getting the below error when we try to deploy the ARM template via ADO YAML Pipeline. Please advise.

The build completes successfully but we get the error in Deploy Stage for Replace token and ARM Templates

A Variable group called POC has been created and stored with all the variables.

Please advise.

ERROR Message:

```
Replace token:
Starting: replacetokens
...
...

replaced 0 tokens out of 0 in 0 file(s) in 0.047 seconds.
Finishing: replacetokens

Starting: ARM Template deployment: Resources
.....
.....

Creating deployment parameters.

##[error]Check out the troubleshooting guide to see if your issue is addressed: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-resource-group-deployment?view=azure-devops#troubleshooting

##[error]Error: Could not find any file matching the template file pattern
Finishing: ARM Template deployment: Resources
```

YAML Pipeline:

```
variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'   
 
  
  ${{ if eq(variables['build.SourceBranchName'], 'poc') }}:  
    groupName: 'POC'
    groupId: '6'      
 

pool:
    vmImage: 'windows-latest'

stages:
        
- stage: Build
  variables:
  - ${{ if eq(variables['build.SourceBranchName'], 'poc') }}:
    - group: POC 
  
  jobs:
  - job: Build     
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest' 
    steps:    
    - task: CopyFiles@2
      displayName: 'Copy Files to: $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)'
      inputs:
        SourceFolder: 'POC/ARM Templates'
        Contents: '*.json'
        TargetFolder: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Deployment/'

    - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
      displayName: 'Publish  Artifact: drop'
      inputs:
            PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Deployment'
            ArtifactName: 'drop'

- stage: DeployPoc
  displayName: 'DeployPoc'
  condition: and(always(), contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/Poc'))
  variables:
   - group: MAPS_PatchTrending-POC
  jobs:  
  - job: 'Deploy'  
    pool:
      vmImage: 'windows-latest'    
    steps:        
        - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
          displayName: 'DownloadBuildArtifacts'
          inputs:
              buildType: 'current'
              downloadType: 'single'
              artifactName: 'drop'
              downloadPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Deployment/'

        - task: replacetokens@3
          inputs:
            rootDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Deployment/'
            targetFiles: 'POC_ARM_Template.parameters.json'
            encoding: 'auto'
            tokenPrefix: '###'
            tokenSuffix: '###'

        - task: AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment@3
          displayName: 'ARM Template deployment: Resources'
          name: ARMDeploy
          enabled: true
          inputs:
              azureResourceManagerConnection: $(PocSpokeConnectedServiceName)
              subscriptionId: $(PocSpokeConnectedSubscriptionID)
              resourceGroupName: $(PocResourceGroup)
              location: $(PocLocation)
              csmFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Deployment/POC_ARM_Template.Json'       
              csmParametersFile: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/Deployment/_ARM_Template.parameters.json'
```

Comment: The name of the `targetFiles` in your `replacetokens` task doesn't match `csmParametersFile` in the `AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeployment` task, they should be the same.  As your logs show no tokens are replaced in the `replacetokens` task then either the `targetFiles` path is wrong or there are no tokens in the file.

Comment: How about the issue? Does the answer below resolved your question, If yes, you could accept it as an answer, so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks. If not, please let us know if you would like further assistance

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the parameters being passed in into the "Override template parameters". The "Template parameters" field is a reference to a file location.
You can refer the doc [Azure Resource Manager (ARM) Template Deployment Task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/AzureResourceManagerTemplateDeploymentV3/README.md)